# Gnuplot stretched ellipse by angle option

Tags: gnuplot, angle, ellipse

I want to draw an ellipse with gnuplot. It should be slightly tilted, hence I use the angle option.
But the angle messes with the size of the ellipse. Am I getting something wrong in the docu?

See the following example:

```
set output "test.pdf"
set obj ellipse center 5,0.5 size 4,0.2 angle 20
set xrange [0:10]
plot sin(x)
```

The added two png's show my results. I use version 5.2.8.
[image: No angle]
[image: With angle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the proportions of the ellipse to remain constant after rotation you must give the major and minor diameters in the same units, e.g. "units xx" or "units yy".  Here I define the ellipse in terms of a 4:1 ratio of major:minor axis using x coordinates.

```
set obj 1 ellipse center 5,0.5 size 4,1 fs empty bo lc "blue"  angle 0   units xx
set obj 2 ellipse center 5,0.5 size 4,1 fs empty bo lc "red"   angle 20  units xx
set obj 3 ellipse center 5,0.5 size 4,1 fs empty bo lc "green" angle 40  units xx
set xrange [0:10]
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution suits my situation best.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Ethan's solution is certainly the way to go.
Just keep in mind, if you don't have `set size ratio -1`, a line, e.g. like `plot x` will not appear in a 45° degree angle to the x-axis.

Probably, the simplest solution would be to `set size ratio -1` to have the same scale for x and y-axis. If you need different scale there should be a different solution.

**Code:**

```
### draw tilted ellipse with same proportions
reset session

set size ratio -1
set obj 1 ellipse center 5,0.5 size 4,0.2 angle 0  fc "red"
set obj 2 ellipse center 5,0.5 size 4,0.2 angle 20 fc "green"
set obj 3 ellipse center 5,0.5 size 4,0.2 angle 45 fc "blue"
set obj 5 ellipse center 5,0.5 size 4,0.2 angle 90 fc "magenta"

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [-3:3]
plot sin(x)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. Adding the ratio line causes the y axe to collapse to a 10th of the screen size. I can fix that by setting a yrange myself. But I would like to use autoscale.

Answer (score 0):

If the output to a dummy file is allowed, how about the following solution.

```
set terminal pdf size 10cm,10cm

set xrange [0:10]

# dummy plotting
set output "dummy.pdf"
plot sin(x)

factor =  real(GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN)/real(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN) \
        * real(GPVAL_TERM_YMAX - GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)/real(GPVAL_TERM_XMAX - GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)

# real plotting
set output "test.pdf"
set obj ellipse center 5,0.5 size 4,factor*0.2 angle 20 unit xx
replot
```

In this script, the ratio of visible unit length between x and y axis is calculated using from variable GPVAL_* determined by the dummy plotting. Multipling it to vertical axis of the ellipse and using 'unit xx' as same as Ethan's answer, you may get the figure that you want.

If you are on UNIX(-like) system, replace 'set output "dummy.pdf"' as,

```
set output "/dev/null"
```

[image]